# Sensitivity Analysis solver python

Tags: python, solver

I am solving for the sensitivity of a cashflow at a certain time period and to do that I want to take my code:

```
while count < (len(netcf)):
    cpv = float(netcf[count]/((1+MARR)**(time[count])))                  
    sum = round((sum+cpv),2)                
    count=count+1
print "Net Present Value = $", sum
```

This calculates the cashflow w/o sensitivity analysis and what I want to do is take certain time periods, say time 0 for simplicity's sake, and multiply the value times (1+x) and solve for the value of "x" so that when you add the new value to the sum of the other looped values, instead of the previous value (w/o 1+x) it brings the present worth as close to 0 as possible.

So far I have tried to utilize "while True" loops to solve for x but I have had no luck.. I am also having trouble keeping the loop from calculating the value w/o (1+x) and only using the value with (1+x) when added to the sum. Any suggestions at this point would be helpful as I've never solved for an unknown in python.

Comment: Your description of what you'd like to do is too vague and garbled to understand. Could you try to explain what you'd like to do in a clearer way?

Comment: In the above code, instead of the `while` loop with `count=count+1` at the end, use a `for` loop: `for count in range(len(netcf)):`. Better yet, just iterate over the `netcf` and `time` sequences together: `for (netcff_value, time_value) in zip(netcf, time):`.

Comment: @taleinat yeah, I struggled writing that just because it's a complex thing for me to try to get out through text. The code I listed works great for me but I would like to keep it from iterating at a certain value (like 5, 3, 7, or 0, just random) and i want to pull the iteration at that time out and perform the second calculation where I would multiply by (1+x) and solve for the value of x that would make the value after that calculation, when added to the sum of the values from the while loop, brings the total sum close to 0

Comment: @taleinat did that help clear anything up?

Comment: Are you having trouble with stopping the loop after a certain amount of iterations, or with solving the equation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sum and you'd like to know which value to add to it in order to get zero, that's just `-sum`. Now, if you want the value of `x` for which `(1 + x) == -sum`, the solution is just `x = -sum - 1`.

**EDIT:** I get the feeling that isn't what you're trying to solve, though...

**EDIT2:** With regard to stopping the loop and then doing a second calculation, just use the `break` statement, e.g.:

```
stop_at = random.choice(range(len(netcf)))
while count < (len(netcf)):
    cpv = float(netcf[count]/((1+MARR)**(time[count])))                  
    sum = round((sum+cpv),2)                
    if count == stop_at:
        break
    count=count+1

print "Net Present Value = $", sum

# now do the second calculation ...
```